# Printing index of certain row in a dataframe - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Please advise what shall be the most optimized way of Printing index for a certain row in a Dataframe?I know its a rookie question but still need help.
I can select the row using dataframe.iloc or dataframe.loc method, but i am struggling with printing the corresponding index.
Eg. of the Dataframe is-
 [image: dataframe]

Here Country column is Index. I want to just print Index name - United States. df.idxmax shall get me the max value index and that is not what i am looking for.

Comment: Please include the statement that selects the row(s) for which you want to know the index. Otherwise, it is unclear what you want. Also, do not paste a screenshot of the DataFrame; paste the text into the question.

Comment: `df[some_condition].index.tolist()`

Comment: @COLDSPEED - Thank you so much for the help. that certainly helped.